# How to select element from options populated

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to write a script with Selenium-Webdriver. I am stuck in a situation where I need to enter text (e.g : `"tt"`) in the textbox and a list gets populated (hidden values). We need to select an option from the populated list. (Like we do in "Google" search).

```
<div class="select2-search">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="select2-input tabindex="-1" style>
</div>
<ul class="select2-results">
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-new">
  <div class="select2-result-label">
    <span class="select2-match">et</span>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
  <div class="select2-result-label">"Secr"
    <span class="select2-match">et</span>"ary"
  </div>
</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i'll write a little code to help you.

I'm using www.google.com as exemple.

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")); // get the input
inputElement.sendKeys("zyzz"); // you want to search him on internet ;)
// get all suggestions in a list
List<WebElement> suggestionList = driver.findElements(By.CssSelector(".gsq_a table tbody tr td:first-of-type span"));
```

To select an option you have 2 choices, first :

```
// you get a random option and click on it
suggestionList.get(1).click();
```

or

```
// you only want to click on the link that contains that.
for(WebElement elem: suggestionList)
{
  String text = elem.getText();
  if(text.equals("zyzz motivation"))
  elem.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me, but it doesn't select the element and No error is displayed when we run the script